# How to link hundreds of my pictures to my products in ecommerce website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

After surfing in the iternet I wasn't able to find any kind of solution about this. I'm bulding a platfor where I've a long list of products, which are displayed in the site. On the other hand I have database with pictures, stored locally, which has to be shown in the web for each respective product. Manual linking each image to the respective product is not a solution due to the products and pictures are more than thousand. Do you have any clever idea where to store and how to link the pictures to the website?

Comment: Do the pictures have logical names?

Comment: Try to find a relation between filename and any of the product unique attributes. Migrate pictures to services such as s3 or any object storage platforms. Make sure the product attribute you selected is in a url format, else parse it. If you are able to consistently keep the uniqueness of the selected attribute, you might not need to store the image name.

Comment: @Martijn yes they do and even match in 100% witht the products from the product's list

Comment: @ManzoorSamad thank will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Store your pictures on an object storage like S3, or even just a disk somewhere. Create a new table that links a picture with a product eg: `products_pictures` with a structure like this:

```
create table products_pictures
(
    id             int auto_increment
        primary key,
    productId        int                  not null,
    pictureLocation text                  not null,
    constraint productFk
        foreign key (productId) references products (id)
            on delete cascade
)
```

If you are using S3, the value for `pictureLocation` should be the Key of the object.

I guess there is no way except to link all the pictures you have a.t.m. manually.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through Array of Object and display all images dynamically.

Let's imagine that you have API like this - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

And you can simply do this:

```
const App = () => {
    const listItems = images.map((image) =>
        <li key={image.id}><img src={image.url} alt={image.title} /></li> 
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {listItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
}
```